# Can we add a tag for Universal Basic Income?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, scope, tags

I'm seeing more and more questions relating to the UBI on here, including one from myself, and there is not yet a tag for it as a topic.

I think it would prevent inaccurate tags to allow people a more specific tag for UBI, as when I looked there wasn't anything as suitable as this.

Comment: Why isn't our [tag:basic-income] tag sufficient?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that one, that will probably do just fine! Thanks

Comment: Ok then, tagging this [status-completed]. For future reference, you can see (and search) all existing tags here: http://politics.stackexchange.com/tags?page=1&tab=popular

Comment: maybe alias UBI to BI tag